# Is it possible to create an arbitrary, stable, unique chemical fingerprint?

Tags: physical-chemistry, theoretical-chemistry, chemical-engineering

Context: I want to be able to hash real-world objects

Is it possible to create a substance containing a combination of elements (or isotopes?) in a random and difficult to reproduce (but simple to verify) combination?

For example if the "fingerprint" was 69% X and 31% Y this information can be easily hashed but it should be very difficult to reproduce with exactly that combination. This substance would then be combined with the object in an unobtrusive way and it should be simple to verify that that object has that exact "fingerprint".

In my mind using DNA/RNA in some way seems like a good solution but I believe it's not very stable. I feel it would be useful only if it lasts at least 20-50 years or so.

Comment: There are a variety of approaches for high-reliability supply chain management that work under vaguely analogous processes. But I don't know the details.

Comment: Related:https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_memory

Comment: I believe that oil is being tagged with DNA. A small amount of DNA is added to the oil and the source of the oil can be identified if it's spilled.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taggant#Explosive_taggants

Comment: I don't think DNA is added to oil, it won't be soluble. It may naturally have some. Oil has a complex chemical signature which is being studied by gas chromatography, liquid chromatography and very advanced mass spectrometry techniques.

Comment: I think one of the points with hashing is simplicity. You could compare the original documents line by line but hashing is just much faster (although perhaps I am thinking more about checksums and the like). A lot of substances can be tested for origin by obtaining a composition profile. This is obviously not a unique identifier, in the way that checksum is. A composition profile is necessary, not sufficient, to show provenance. But simply spiking with a combination of stable molecules as you suggest might be good enough to ensure a unique fingerprint.